# WordPress fails to embed video URL

Tags: embed, youtube

WordPress or my theme fails to embed this video URL:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/vsTrAfJFLXI?rel=0?controls=0`

but works with this URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsTrAfJFLXI
```

I need to get rid of the youtube control buttons in the preview, but cannot use embed or the iframe because that just creates an hyperlink. Any ideas?

WP version 3.7.1

Comment: I'm not sure if WordPress recognizes such urls. Why can't you just put this video in normal (second) url form? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to loose the bottom control bar and just leave the play icon in the center of the video. And the control bar would appear once the player clicks the play icon.

Comment: Do you want this look on all youtube videos? Or only on this one?

Comment: On all of the videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `&controls=0` instead of `?controls=0`solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching off all your plugins and changing the theme to see if anything might be causing a conflict of some sort? If it works, then start by changing your theme back, refreshing the page and seeing that works. Introduce the plugins one by one and refresh the page to see if any of those might be the culprit?

Comment: I've only have one plugin activated and that is the advanced code editor. Deactivating it made no difference.

Comment: Please note that this kind of debug-ish narrowing down is considered more suitable as comments on the question rather than answer.